# Obtener el color de un LCD Number de QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Para insertar el color en uno de mis LCD Number simplemente uso la instrucción:

```
this->ui->lcdNumber_23->setPalette(Qt::red);
```

Pero no encuentro cómo obtener el color actual que tiene un LCD Number, he probado a obtener la paleta pero no encuentro el método get. El objetivo es realizar una comparación ya que dependiendo del color actual que tenga el número, le pondré uno u otro.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> he probado a obtener la paleta pero no encuentro el método get

[QLCDNumber](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html) hereda de [QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) y este objeto tiene una propiedad llamada [`palette`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#palette-prop). Mirando ahí vemos que es una propiedad de lectura y escritura. La escritura se hace, como bien has comentado, con `setPalette`, mientras que la lectura se realiza con el método `palette`

```
 QPalette const& palette = ui->lcdNumber_23->palette();
```

O, si no quieres usar referencias y quieres copiar el objeto:

```
QPalette palette = ui->lcdNumber_23->palette();
```

---

A raiz del comentario:

> Si, así obtengo la paleta, pero luego, ¿cómo obtengo el color de la paleta que es lo que no soy capaz de encontrar?

Fíjate que cuando llamas a `setPalette` no le estás pasando una paleta como tal sino un `QGlobalColor`, que es un enumerado. A partir de ese enumerado el compilador tiene que crear un objeto de tipo `QPalete`, si no fuese capaz aparecería un error en tiempo de compilación pero no es el caso.

Si revisamos, por tanto, la documentación de [`QPalette`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html), vemos que tiene un [constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#QPalette-2) que acepta un `Qt::GlobalColor`. La documentación de ese método dice lo siguiente:

> Constructs a palette from the button color. The other colors are automatically calculated, based on this color. Window will be the button color as well.

Es decir, en base a ese color se calcula toda la paleta de colores. Y el rol que almacena el color pasado como argumento es `Window`... basta con recuperar el color asociado a ese rol para tener el color buscado. Para ello tenemos el método [`color`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#color-1):

```
QColor color = palette.color(QPalette::Window);
```

Y listo, con eso deberías obtener el color buscado.

Comment: Si, así obtengo la paleta, pero luego, ¿cómo obtengo el color de la paleta que es lo que no soy capaz de encontrar?.